# UWP NavigationView not lining up with titlebar back button

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to line up my NavigationView with the back button that comes built into the window like so:

[[image: lined up bar]]

but when i try to line up my NavigationView it ends up looking like

[[image: this]]

How should i go about changing the width of the NavigationView so that it lines up with the back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the back button isn't aligned for you is that you're using the embedded back button in the title bar, which is deprecated now (as in, the MS guidelines suggest not to use it anymore, and to replace it with a dedicated back button in the app UI).

What you want to do is to set the `IsBackButtonVisible` property of the `NavigationView` to `Visible`, and use that back button instead to handle the navigation in your frame, or in other parts of your app.

To handle the back navigation request, you can just register to the `BackRequested` event in the `NavigationView` control.

Also, to hide the back button in the title bar, you just need to remove these couple lines in your code:

```cs
var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
```

Comment: That somewhat worked, but now the back button inst in the title bar and is instead just underneath it [like this](https://imgur.com/a/w1eOm4N)

Comment: As I said, that is the expected behavior, you'll see the same thing in the Store app as well, for instance. This is done to make the UI of all the apps more consistent, given the fact that the title bar is not always present (eg. full screen apps don't have that, or apps running on mobile devices or Xbox).
Please don't forget to mark the answer as valid if it solved your problem.

Comment: Also it is because of the upcoming Sets feature

Comment: @MartinZikmund That is correct, it was definitely one of the reasons why that back button was deprecated 